# Custom sorting - different for strings and floats

Tags: java, sorting, compare

I'm sorting a list of arrays containing strings according to a custom `.sort`. These are actually values from a table. Sometimes the strings can actually be a float (as a string object). So the entire column would be a float. If so I want them to be compared as floats not as strings. Any idea how I can modify the following code for that to work? I should be able to check if it's a float using try / catch but then how do I change the sorting?

```
static Comparator<String[]> byIndices(int[] arr) {
        Comparator<String[]> comparator = comparing((array) -> array[arr[0]]);
        int c = 0;
        for (int index : arr) {
            if (c == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            comparator = comparator.thenComparing((array) -> array[index]);
            c++;
        }
        return comparator;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try to create a factory for comparators. Which would return the comparator instance based upon weather you need String comparison or Float comparison. Below is a pseudo code

```
ComparatorFactory{
  public Comparator getComparator(String inputType)
      if(// inputType is float){
       // return float comparator;
      }
      // return String comparator

}
```

Comment: hmm can't seem to figure out how to get this to work. Could you please provide a little more info. Really appreciate it